# windows xp cannot access admin share

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, network-share

I have 3 systems. A,B,Compx  all on xp.
but comps A and B have an issue with Compx.

Compx has network shares I can access.
I can do  \\compx  and get some.

But I cannot access the admin share c$
\\compx\c$  gives a login prompt, and I can't get any user/pass to work.

I looked at permissions but don't see an issue.

Nevertheless, I will describe what I see in the permissions.

In the security tab of C, I have
Administrators,creator owner,everyone,bob,system,users  (6 things there)
"creator owner" has nothing ticked, I can't seem to change that. If I tick so they all get ticked, and click apply, 2.5min and it's completed its opration and they all untick.  Though this isn't the root of the problem. Since I get the same in the share I can access.

In advanced, I see those 6 things,
Administrators,creator owner,everyone,bob,system,users  (6 things there)
all "full control"
all are "this folder, subfolders and files".. except creator owner, which is just subfolders and files only

I look at the properties for the share I can see.
looks the same, except in security..advanced, double clicking any of them the boxes are all ticked but greyed.  That's not the problem though since I can access that share.

So, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Are these computers joined to an AD domain? Are they in workgroup mode? When your prompted for credentials, what are you inputting?

Comment: SFS disabled, Guest disabled.

Comment: Not connected to an AD domain .  Workgroup mode. For credentials, i've tried user/pass for the current account on the machine(which is administrative), and for Administrator, and for another administrative account called Admin. Each has a password. But it's not working.. after the login screen, when I try e.g. Administrator and the password, it says "c$ is not accessible, you might not have permission .."

Comment: Those credentials you're entering, are they valid on the machine you are connecting to? You might also check to ensure nobody has fiddled with the target machine's local policy settings.

Comment: yes. which local policy settings should I be looking at?

Comment: Have you tried using the credentials compx\user and that users password?

Answer (score 1):

As their name suggests, admin shares can be accessed only by users that are administrators on that computer.

You need to create the same user in every computer, and that user must be administrator in all of them. It should have a password, because in some occasions users without passwords won't work.

Note use that you if you renamed a user this won't work, since renamed users maintain their original network name.

Answer (score 0):

I've had NIGHTMARES with this.

try with start-->execute:

`\\personalcomputerip\c$`

And, of course, disable any firewall / antivirus program.

Double check both share and security permission for your user of interest.
Done that check on random files single file in any folder if permissions were propagated (important).

Once understood what was wrong put things together again.

Comment: I suspect you mean \\computer\ipc$...?

Comment: no: I mean "your computer ip" :)

c$ is the default admin share for c: in windows xp

Comment: Ok. \\computer\ipc$ is a default interprocess communication (I suppose) share that allows you to list shares etc; see e.g. http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-ipc-share.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues in the past try disabling simple file sharing in the remote computer 
its under folder options --> View tab --> Use simple file sharing.

Hope this helps you sort the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Settings.
2. In the left pane, expand Local Policies > Security Options.
3. In the right pane, double-click Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts.
4. Select "Classic - local users authenticate as themselves," and click OK.

[Source](https://forum.sysinternals.com/access-denied-windows-xp-pro-sp2_topic1411.html)